# Big random number generation

Tags: php, random

I need a big (like, say, 128-bit big) random number generator in PHP. I was thinking in storing this number in a string as hexadecimal.

Note that this is meant for a login system that mentioned the need for a "random" number, so I'm guessing I *really* need it to be "random-enough" (because I know pseudo-random is never truly random).

The algorithm I was thinking was generating the number one hex digit at a time, then concatenating it all. Like this:

```
$random = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 32; ++$i) {
   $digit = rand(0, 15);
   $random .= ($digit < 10 ? $digit : ($digit - 10 + 'a'));
}
return $random;
```

Can I trust this function to return good pseudo-random numbers or am I messing with something I really shouldn't?

Comment: Your solution uses `rand`, which is not secure. Are you sure you need 128 bits? Anyway, [`Random::alphanumericString(22)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) provides that. Or a UUID, e.g. via `Random::uuid4()`, which is 14 characters longer, though.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
for ($str = '', $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $str .= dechex(mt_rand(0, 15));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question several years ago and, since then, my knowledge of this topic has improved.

First of all, I mentioned I wanted random numbers for a login system. Login systems are security mechanisms.
This means that any random number generators that the login system relies on should be  **cryptographically secure**.

PHP's `rand` and `mt_rand` are not cryptographically secure.

In these cases, it's best to be safe than sorry. There are random number generators designed specifically to be secure, notably [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) (which is unfortunately not always available -- you must enable the OpenSSL extension for it to work). On *NIX systems (such as Linux), bytes read from `/dev/urandom` [can be used](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key) as well.

Unfortunately (for the purposes of this question), both of these approaches return binary data instead of hexadecimal. Fortunately, PHP already has a function to fix this for us, [`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php), which works for strings of any length.

So here's how the code would look like:

```
function generate_secure_random_hex_string($length) {
   // $length should be an even, non-negative number.

   // Because each byte is represented as two hex digits, we'll need the binary
   // string to be half as long as the hex string.
   $binary_length = $length / 2;

   // First, we'll generate the random binary string.
   $random_result = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($binary_length, $cstrong);

   if (!$cstrong) {
      // The result is not cryptographically secure. Abort.
      // die() is just a placeholder.
      // There might be better ways to handle this error.
      die();
   }

   //Convert the result to hexadecimal
   return bin2hex($random_result);
}

// Example:
echo generate_secure_random_hex_string(32);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen this handled in login systems by just doing something like:

```
$salt  = "big string of random stuff"; // you can generate this once like above
$token = md5( $salt . time()); // this will be your "unique" number
```

MD5 hashes can have collisions, but this is pretty effective and very simple.

Comment: Why not just replace $salt by rand()? Wouldn't it be equally random? Heck, probably even more random.

Comment: that's true, but using rand() will negate your ability to compare the expected hash, if you want to do that. EG. in password situations, you often will hash the users' password with a salt-- then since you presumably are the only one who knows the salt, you can then compare the hash you've recorded in the DB for that user with the "expected hash", and you can verify that it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3:

```
function getRandomHex($num_bytes=4) {
  return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($num_bytes));
}
```

For your example of 128 bits:

```
$rand128 = getRandomHex(16);
```